# Power platform canvas app, how do I create a new detail record using an edit form

Tags: powerapps-canvas, dataverse

I have a master/detail relationship between two dataverse tables.  The detail record has a file column.  In a single screen I need to allow the user to save both the master and the detail record together.

For the data entry of the master records fields, I have components bound to context properties and when the user clicks save I do a Patch.

For the detail record I've added an Edit Form component and selected by detail table as the data source, which gives me the attachment component so that the user can upload a file.  I then bind the Items property to a context property which I populated using a Lookup in the OnVisible of my screen, so if I am viewing/editing the Edit Form component displays the correct detail information associated to the master record.

What I'm struggling with is how to handle an insert scenario.  The Patch for the master record works fine. But how does the insert for the detail record work?  It has to have a reference to the master record.  So after the save of the master, I need to provide that to the detail record prior to save that, and I don't know how to do that.